# Maintaining plugin customizations on top of trunk

Tags: wordpress, git, svn

I am looking to make a few customizations to the [Memberful Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/memberful-wp/) that will meld the plugin with my [existing website](https://moabtimes.com) just a bit better than it currently does in staging.

Ideally, the plugin would be maintained with Git, and I could make a branch with my customizations, and with each update that the Memberful team launches, I would rebase my branch onto the new master, test, and re-deploy.

Unfortunately, the Memberful Wordpress plugin is (and all other Wordpress plugins are?) maintained with Subversion.

Is there a way I can achieve my desired ends using Git? Or is it more advisable that I use Subversion for this part of development and learn to rebase in Subversion?

Comment: Not what you asked but how about asking the developer of the plugin to make it extendable (action/filter hooks, OOP, etc) so you can customize it from outside according to your needs? (Or even better, send PRs implementing action/filter hooks to extend the functionality of the plugin).

Comment: @cabrerahector that's a good idea. I'll definitely communicate with the development team regarding that. As a more general point, I think would be good practice generally for parties implementing software and seeking extendability to communicate that desire to the original developer or, as you suggest, directly contribute that extendability feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: [This guide](https://gist.github.com/kasparsd/3749872) is extremely helpful in figuring out how to do all of this.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085482/599097) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177192/599097) shows the process for rebasing in Subversion. It goes as follows:

1. `svn cp trunk feature`
2. commits to feature & trunk
3. `svn cp trunk feature-rebase`
4. `svn co feature-rebase`
5. `cd feature-rebase`
6. `svn merge feature`
7. `svn commit`
8. `svn rm feature`
9. `svn mv feature-rebase feature`
10. (back on feature-rebase WC) `svn switch feature`

So, what I would do in this case is use Subversion for development (not desirable in my case) and keep my local, development `trunk` up-to-date with the remote `trunk` using [`svn update`](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html).

## Preferred alternative

A preferred alternative that I found, which allows me to continue working in Git is by exploiting a [robust set of commands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) that is included as a part of `git-svn` that allows bidirectional operations between a Subversion repository and  Git.

I believe all I need to do (although I have not yet tested this) is [`git svn init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-eminitem) a local development environment based on the remote trunk location (in my specific case, that is [Memberful's Subversion repository](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/memberful-wp/) and, whenever I need to "pull" changes from the remote repository, use [`git svn rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-emrebaseem).